# periodically delete entries in objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, objectify

I'm using Google App Engine with Objectify and would like to delete some entries in the db every 5 minutes. What would be the best way to accomplish this? Should I use Google App Engine's ThreadManager or a cron job? Or is there another way?

Comment: How many entries that are intended to be deleted every five minutes?

Comment: @IbrahimArief: Many many, perhaps a few hundred thousand? Or is there a way to expire these entries automatically?

Comment: That's.. huge. The only way to expire a shared data automatically is by using [expiration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/Expiration) option in Memcache when you do a [put operation](http://bit.ly/10S6xve), but then your data would be transient. Deleting hundreds of thousands entities that frequently would also be very expensive, are you sure about the scale?

Comment: @IbrahimArief:
Yeah, theoretically it could be as many as that. I did consider using the expiration option in Memcache, but I also need to do some operations on the data, like count it for example. The data can be transient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cron](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron) sounds like fitting the requirement here, but I'm worried about the scale of entities that need to be deleted. (Up to a few hundred thousands every five minutes according to the comments). Deleting that many entities takes a considerable amount of time, most likely more than the five minutes period, and might even be more than the 10 minutes deadline for front-end cron handlers.

One possible solution is to do the deletion from the [backend instance](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview), since backends could run without any deadline. Crons could be used to kick up a process that queries for to-be-deleted entities, fetch their keys using key-only query, and then delete the entities in multiple [background threads](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview#background_threads).

Since the process could run indefinitely, after the threads report that the deletion finishes, you could immediately query again and delete the next set of entities. You could use a global in-memory lock in the backend to ensure subsequent cron requests are not kicking up a separate process, but silently exit if it detects that the process already runs. So here the cron is used only as a keep-alive signal for the deletion process.

As a side note, please note that querying and deleting entities this frequently and at this scale might be prohibitively expensive in terms of datastore operation cost.

Comment: I don't believe this will work because you can't get enough datastore operation throughput from a single instance. The only way this will work is via map/reduce, and it's going to cost at least $150/day just in datastore ops. More if you want to read the data... and that has timing issues too.

Comment: @stickfigure: Thanks Jeff, I was wondering about the throughput too. As much as I like mapreduce, I don't know if it provides the kind of fine grained control that the asker needs. (We were previously discussing it in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15976406/objectify-and-timertask-no-api-environment-is-registered-for-this-thread?lq=1)) If it were my app, I would use some sort of master-worker pattern to distribute the load and deletion, but that might be a bit overkill compared to changing the implementation strategy altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want, every 5 minutes, to:

- Write hundreds of thousands of entities
- Aggregate hundreds of thousands of entities
- Delete hundreds of thousands of entities

It's possible to do this with map/reduce. However, it will be expensive (hundreds of dollars per day), and you're going to have timing issues - especially when the task queue backs up.

You should strongly consider storing this data outside GAE. Get a Google Compute Engine account and set up a mongodb or redis instance there. Or even host it on AWS. GAE is not well suited for this sort of workload, but it's not "all or nothing" - you can easily work with services in other parts of the cloud.