# Objectify doesn't work inside createThreadForCurrentRequest()

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

This is a follow-up question to [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15979300/193550).

I have the following code in a servlet:

```
createThreadForCurrentRequest(() => {
    // do stuff
}).start();
```

But when I run it locally, I received this exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-17" java.lang.IllegalStateException: You have not started an Objectify context. You are probably missing the ObjectifyFilter. If you are not running in the context of an http request, see the ObjectifyService.run() method.
```

Where do I do wrong?

**To paraphrase:** How do I run Objectify inside thread spawned by `createThreadForCurrentRequest()`?

**EDIT 1:** By request, here's the `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         metadata-complete="true">

    <absolute-ordering/>

    <!-- Register Objectify model -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>foo.ObjectifyListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>objectify</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>objectify</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>bar</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>foo.BarServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>bar</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/foo/bar/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**EDIT 2:**

I use the new (currently in beta) Java 8 runtime.

Comment: can you please post your web.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a unit of work (exactly the same way the filter does) like this:

```
ObjectifyService.run(() -> {
    ofy().load()...etc
});
```

Also see the `begin()` method, which is pretty much the same thing (you can use try-with-resources instead of passing a closure).

Comment: Here is the docs: https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Utilising-Objectify-Outside-of-Context